# How to extract text from span surrounded by div using beautifulsoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have a html snippet as below:

```html
<div class="single_baby_name_description">
    <label>Meaning :</label> <span class="28816-meaning">the meaning of this name is universal whole.</span> </br>
    <label>Gender :</label> <span class="28816-gender">Girl</span> </br>
    <label>Religion :</label> <span class="28816-religion">Christianity</span> </br>
    <label>Origin :</label> <span class="28816-origin">German,French,Swedish</span> </br>
</div>
```

I attempt to extract  text from all span inside div using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
spans=soup.select('div.single_baby_name_description>span')
```

But spans[0].text gets only the text from the first tag .
And spans[1].text occurs IndexError: list index out of range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that only 'lxml' will do the job. For some reason 'html.parser' won't.

This will work:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
spans = soup.select('div.single_baby_name_description span')
spans = [span.text for span in spans]
print(spans)
```

Output:

```
['the meaning of this name is universal whole.', 'Girl', 'Christianity', 'German,French,Swedish']
```

Comment: Thanks，I switch to another parser 'lxml' jus now. It works.

Comment: I recommend you using lxml over html.parser anyway. By the way, see edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the beautiful soup docs

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup

selecting an attribute by tag name just returns the first one found as you’ve described. Have you tried:

```
Soup.find_all(‘span’)
```